# Generating substrings and random strings in R

Tags: string, r, list, text, random

Please bear with me, I come from a Python background and I am still learning string manipulation in R.

Ok, so lets say I have a string of length 100 with random A, B, C, or D letters:

```
> df<-c("ABCBDBDBCBABABDBCBCBDBDBCBDBACDBCCADCDBCDACDDCDACBCDACABACDACABBBCCCBDBDDCACDDACADDDDACCADACBCBDCACD")
> df
[1]"ABCBDBDBCBABABDBCBCBDBDBCBDBACDBCCADCDBCDACDDCDACBCDACABACDACABBBCCCBDBDDCACDDACADDDDACCADACBCBDCACD"
```

I would like to do the following two things:

1) Generate a '.txt' file that is comprised of 20-length subsections of the above string, each starting one letter after the previous with their own unique name on the line above it, like this:

```
NAME1
ABCBDBDBCBABABDBCBCB
NAME2
BCBDBDBCBABABDBCBCBD
NAME3
CBDBDBCBABABDBCBCBDB
NAME4
BDBDBCBABABDBCBCBDBD
```

... and so forth

2) Take that generated list and from it comprise another list that has the same exact substrings with the only difference being a change of one or two of the A, B, C, or Ds to another A, B, C, or D (any of those four letters only).

So, this:

```
NAME1
ABCBDBDBCBABABDBCBCB
```

Would become this:

```
NAME1.1
ABBBDBDBCBDBABDBCBCB
```

As you can see, the "C" in the third position became a "B" and the "A" in position 11 became a "D", with no implied relationship between those changed letters. Purely random.

I know this is a convoluted question, but like I said, I am still learning basic text and string manipulation in R.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to replace the one or two letters with the identical letter, i.e., is it allowed to replace, e.g., `A` with `A`? Is it really random?

Answer (score 4):

I tried breaking this down into multiple simple steps, hopefully you can get learn a few tricks from this:

```
# Random data
df<-c("ABCBDBDBCBABABDBCBCBDBDBCBDBACDBCCADCDBCDACDDCDACBCDACABACDACABBBCCCBDBDDCACDDACADDDDACCADACBCBDCACD")
n<-10 # Number of cuts
set.seed(1)
# Pick n random numbers between 1 and the length of string-20
nums<-sample(1:(nchar(df)-20),n,replace=TRUE)
# Make your cuts
cuts<-sapply(nums,function(x) substring(df,x,x+20-1))
# Generate some names
nams<-paste0('NAME',1:n)
# Make it into a matrix, transpose, and then recast into a vector to get alternating names and cuts.
names.and.cuts<-c(t(matrix(c(nams,cuts),ncol=2)))
# Drop a file.
write.table(names.and.cuts,'file.txt',quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE,col.names = FALSE)

# Pick how many changes are going to be made to each cut.
changes<-sample(1:2,n,replace=2)
# Pick that number of positions to change
pos.changes<-lapply(changes,function(x) sample(1:20,x))
# Find the letter at each position.
letter.at.change.pos<-lapply(pos.changes,function(x) substring(df,x,x))
# Make a function that takes any letter, and outputs any other letter from c(A-D)                             
letter.map<-function(x){
    # Make a list of alternate letters.
    alternates<-lapply(x,setdiff,x=c('A','B','C','D'))
    # Pick one of each
    sapply(alternates,sample,size=1)
}
# Find another letter for each
letter.changes<-lapply(letter.at.change.pos,letter.map)
# Make a function to replace character by position
# Inefficient, but who cares.
rep.by.char<-function(str,pos,chars){
  for (i in 1:length(pos)) substr(str,pos[i],pos[i])<-chars[i]
  str
}

# Change every letter at pos.changes to letter.changes
mod.cuts<-mapply(rep.by.char,cuts,pos.changes,letter.changes,USE.NAMES=FALSE)
# Generate names
nams<-paste0(nams,'.1')
# Use the matrix trick to alternate names.Drop a file.
names.and.mod.cuts<-c(t(matrix(c(nams,mod.cuts),ncol=2)))
write.table(names.and.mod.cuts,'file2.txt',quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE,col.names = FALSE)
```

---

Also, instead of the `rep.by.char` function, you could just use `strsplit` and `replace` like this:

```
mod.cuts<-mapply(function(x,y,z) paste(replace(x,y,z),collapse=''),
   strsplit(cuts,''),pos.changes,letter.changes,USE.NAMES=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! User like you are exactly why Stack is pivotal to learning.

Comment: I liked @SvenHohenstein use of `strsplit` and `replace` so I showed how you could do that here.

Comment: Lots of really great nuggets in that code.  Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a text file of substrings

   ```
   n <- 20 # length of substrings

   starts <- seq(nchar(df) - 20 + 1)

   v1 <- mapply(substr, starts, starts + n - 1, MoreArgs = list(x = df))

   names(v1) <- paste0("NAME", seq_along(v1), "\n")

   write.table(v1, file = "filename.txt", quote = FALSE, sep = "",
               col.names = FALSE)
   ```
2. Randomly replace one or two letters (A-D):

   ```
   myfun <- function() {
     idx <- sample(seq(n), sample(1:2, 1))
     rep <- sample(LETTERS[1:4], length(idx), replace = TRUE)
     return(list(idx = idx, rep = rep))
   }

   new <- replicate(length(v1), myfun(), simplify = FALSE)

   v2 <- mapply(function(x, y, z) paste(replace(x, y, z), collapse = ""),  
                strsplit(v1, ""),
                lapply(new, "[[", "idx"),
                lapply(new, "[[", "rep"))

   names(v2) <- paste0(names(v2), ".1")

   write.table(v2, file = "filename2.txt", quote = FALSE, sep = "\n", 
               col.names = FALSE)
   ```

Comment: Very nice. I should have thought of the `strsplit` and `replace` combo. I think you don't guarantee that the replaced letter will be *different*. `A` could replaced with `A`.

Comment: @nograpes Unfortunately, the OP didn't answer my comment. From the question: *with no implied relationship between those changed letters. Purely random.*

Answer (score 2):

One way, albeit slowish:

```
Rgames> foo<-paste(sample(c('a','b','c','d'),20,rep=T),sep='',collapse='')
Rgames> bar<-matrix(unlist(strsplit(foo,'')),ncol=5)
Rgames> bar
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "c"  "c"  "a"  "c"  "a" 
[2,] "c"  "c"  "b"  "a"  "b" 
[3,] "b"  "b"  "a"  "c"  "d" 
[4,] "c"  "b"  "a"  "c"  "c"
```

Now you can select random indices and replace the selected locations with `sample(c('a','b','c','d'),1)` .  For "true" randomness, I wouldn't even force a change - if your newly drawn letter is the same as the original,  so be it.
Like this:

```
ibar<-sample(1:5,4,rep=T) # one random column number for each row
for ( j in 1: 4) bar[j,ibar[j]]<-sample(c('a','b','c','d'),1)
```

Then, if necessary,  recombine each row using `paste`

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of your question:

```
df <- c("ABCBDBDBCBABABDBCBCBDBDBCBDBACDBCCADCDBCDACDDCDACBCDACABACDACABBBCCCBDBDDCACDDACADDDDACCADACBCBDCACD")

nstrchars <- 20
count<- nchar(df)-nstrchars

length20substrings <- data.frame(length20substrings=sapply(1:count,function(x)substr(df,x,x+20)))

# to save to a text file.  I chose not to include row names or a column name in the .txt file file
write.table(length20substrings,"length20substrings.txt",row.names=F,col.names=F)
```

For the second part:

```
# create a function that will randomly pick one or two spots in a string and replace
# those spots with one of the other characters present in the string:

changefxn<- function(x){
 x<-as.character(x)
 nc<-nchar(as.character(x))
 id<-seq(1,nc)
 numchanges<-sample(1:2,1)
 ids<-sample(id,numchanges) 
 chars2repl<-strsplit(x,"")[[1]][ids]
 charspresent<-unique(unlist(strsplit(x,"")))
 splitstr<-unlist(strsplit(x,""))
 if (numchanges>1) {
 splitstr[id[1]] <- sample(setdiff(charspresent,chars2repl[1]),1)
 splitstr[id[2]] <- sample(setdiff(charspresent,chars2repl[2]),1)
 }
 else {splitstr[id[1]] <- sample(setdiff(charspresent,chars2repl[1]),1)
 }
 newstr<-paste(splitstr,collapse="")
 return(newstr)
}

# try it out

changefxn("asbbad")
changefxn("12lkjaf38gs")

# apply changefxn to all the substrings from part 1

length20substrings<-length20substrings[seq_along(length20substrings[,1]),]
newstrings <- lapply(length20substrings, function(ii)changefxn(ii))
```